# Worklight 6.2.0.01 fails to subscribe for push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We're having a problem with the device registering for GCM push on worklight using the eclipse studio with version 6.2.0.01 of worklight.

The problem is in the `__isDeviceSupportPush` function in the worklight.js file, returning `undefined` because of which the device does not register for GCM.

```
this.__isDeviceSupportPush = function() {
       var androidSDKVersion = WL.Client.__getAndroidSDKVersion(); // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
       return  androidSDKVersion != undefined && parseInt(androidSDKVersion) >= 8;
};
```

However there is no such problem in worklight 6.2.0.00, and the function defined in the same file worklight.js is different:

```
this.__isDeviceSupportPush = function() {
        return typeof device.version != undefined && parseFloat(device.version.substr(0, 3)) >= 2.2;
};
```

And this works, device registers for GCM successfully.
Any fix or update for this in worklight 6.2.0.01?

Thanks.

Comment: The development team is currently looking into this.

Comment: Is this problem seen in the Push Notifications Getting Started sample? Also whats the Android version of the device where the problem is seen?

Comment: With Push Notifications Getting Started sample am not able to recreate the issue.The WL version is 6.2.0.01.20141120-1827. Tested on Android 4.1.2 device and 4.2.2 emulator. So as asked above kindly confirm if you can recreate in Push Notifications Getting Started sample?If it is not seen in the sample, then can you create a sample where the issue can be recreated? Also whats the Android version of the device where the problem is seen?

Comment: Yes, it happens on the push sample as well. One difference I see is that your WL version is different from mine, the one I have after an update is 6.2.0.01-20141027-1531, yours looks like an updated one? The way I update is through the marketplace and as of now I don't see any new updates.

Comment: What is the Android version of the device where the problem is seen?

Comment: Even with 6.2.0.01-20141027-1531 am not able to recreate the issue with the push getting started sample. Can you send your project to check what went wrong? Also the Android device version?

Comment: @penguin, we are still waiting to hear back from you.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments, the problem cannot be reproduced in the mentioned Worklight 6.2.0.01 version.

To use the latest iFix for Worklight 6.2.0.01, you need to download it from [IBM Fix Central](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral).
The Eclipse Marketplace holds only the very latest release, which is now v6.3.